# Issue with illuminate request when upgrading to laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am getting the following code error after trying to upgrade to laravel 6 from 5.8, has anyone experienced this before?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 68 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:120
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php(68): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection), NULL, NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(799): Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(681): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\ in C:\xampp\htdocs\rebuild\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 120
```

Comment: What is your PHP version? Have you tried to upgrade Laravel via Composer?

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is already listing on on [Laravel repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671) and on [Laracasts](http://%20https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cannot-run-php-artisan?page=1)

It seems the problem is because of `url()` and `asset()` Helper functions used within in configuration files.

To resolve this error use `config()` or `base_path` or define absolute or relative paths in your config files instead of `url()` and `assset()` function for e.g

```
'cdn' => url('vendor/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'),
```

**Changing it to**

```
'cdn' => Config('app.url').'/vendor/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
```

Change `asset('home')` to `base_path('public/home'),`

> **NOTE:** You shouldn't use laravel dependencies inside config because the
>   config is loaded early in the request life cycle and things like
>   global helpers may not be available.

If you are using some dependencies in config file define them in `.env` files